# How does Terrain Compensation work?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, cartesian-closed-categories

Does anybody know the math behind terrain compensation? All I know is that to make these calculations, sensors such as accelerometers and gyroscopes, are mounted in different axes to compensate for roll, pitch, and yaw. What equations/formulas are used to convert the data from the sensors and figure out the correct position?

[Example of Position Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1vwb.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: $3.5$ m $\cdot \sin 10$° $=0.61$ m